# Why is NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate 'changeObject' being called

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm using some boilerplate code that implements the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` in a UITableView. When I perform a segue away from the table view, this delegate method gets called:

```
    func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController,
                didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject,
                atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?,
                forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType,
                newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {

    guard let newIndexPath = newIndexPath else{
        fatalError("No indexPath received") // Gets to this line, thus causing a crash
    }
    switch(type){

    case .Insert:
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

    case .Delete:
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

    case .Update:
        tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

    case .Move:
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    }

}
```

It keeps crashing because a nil value is being passed in for the parameter 'newIndexPath'. I'm able to bypass this by setting my fetchedResultsController variable (the variable responsible for calling the delegate methods) to nil when I call `prepareForSegue`.

Why does this method get called on a segue? And how can I pass in the correct `newIndexPath`? Should I even worry about this? It doesn't seem like setting the variable responsible for calling this delegate method to nil is a very graceful way to take care of this problem.

Comment: I cannot tell from the given information *why* didChangeObject is called. But your check for `newIndexPath` makes no sense at that point, `newIndexPath` is only set for Insert or Move events, but not for Delete or Update events (where you would use `indexPath` instead).

Comment: Don't know how or why, but when I got rid of the check for `newIndexPath` and used `indexPath` instead of `newIndexPath` for the Delete and Update events, it worked just fine without needing to set the fetchedResultsController variable to nil in my `prepareForSegue` method. If you create this as an answer I will select it as the correct solution.

Comment: Simple advice: Just leave the delegate method as it is and delete the `guard` line. Everything is going to be fine. If there ever was a potential crash, Apple would have implemented a protection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens when your FRC delegate receives `.Delete` change:

> `newIndexPath` The destination path for the object for insertions or moves (this value is nil for a deletion).

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate/controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:

You should use `indexPath` with `.Delete`, `.Update` and with `tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` in `.Move` section.

Use `newIndexPath` for `.Insert` and `tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths` in `.Move` section.